# What path should I choose?

Tags: probability

Imagine that I am participating in a contest.

It consists of:

- There are 3 types of objects in a box, and each type, is the same number of times in the box.
- To win, I must grab the same amount of each object.
- Initially, I can only grab 3 objects, therefore to win, I must grab each item once (once type 1, once type 2 and once type 3).

If I do not win the first time, they offer me the following:

1) You can grab 3 more objects, to try to match the quantities (knowing that the quantities are different, but without knowing the quantities)

2) You can grab 6 more objects, to try to match the quantities (knowing that the quantities are different, but without knowing the quantities)

Quickly, I might think that grabbing 6 more objects will give me more opportunities to match, but it will also give me more opportunities to make the difference between the amounts, even bigger.

So, what is better? Pick 6 more objects to grab or 3?

Also assuming they are equiprobable.

My thought was that, it is better to choose 6 objects following the logic of the law of big numbers, however I realized that this law applies when there are many attempts. So, what is the correct one?

Comment: Well, if the "repeated number of times" is that there are three instances of each type, then taking all nine objects is a sure win.

Comment: Why ? if i pick with nine tries: A-A-A-B-A-A-C-C-A ? The object B = 1 times, C = 2 times,  A = 6 times

Comment: In that case, you need 1 of A and 2 of C, because 2A, 2B, 2C

Comment: @Mattiu Are you replacing the objects in the box after grabbing them?

Comment: As you take out the objects, they are left less, without adding

Comment: One thing to notice is that if you happen to pick 3 of the same item the first time, you have no chance of winning unless you grab 6 the second time.

Comment: If I had noticed, but there are quite a few particular cases and I am looking for a general idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Remark**: This answer was given assuming you can *see* what you wound up with on the first grab, but user Anonymous has pointed out that the OP only wants you to know whether you did *or did not* win, so that you have to base your choice of grabbing another three or another six without knowing whether you are currently holding three of one type or two of one type and one of another. I'm leaving the answer as is for now, in case it's of use for the OP or anyone else. **End remark.**

As saulspatz observed in comments, if on the first round you wind up with three of one type, you cannot win if you only grab another three objects, so you *must* opt to grab six more objects to have any hope of winding up with three of each type. So we need only concern ourselves with what to do if we wind up with two of one type, say type A, and one of another, say type B.

If we imagine the box started with an unknown number N of each type, we are left with $N-2$ objects of type A, $N-1$ objects of type B, and $N$ objects of type C.  If we grab three more items, hoping to get two type C's and one more type B, the probability of winning is

$${N-2\choose0}{N-1\choose1}{N\choose2}\over{3N-3\choose3}$$

On the other hand, if we grab *six* more items, hoping to get three of type C, two of type B, and one of type A, the probability of winning is

$${N-2\choose1}{N-1\choose2}{N\choose3}\over{3N-3\choose6}$$

(Note: we must assume $N\ge3$ in order for this option to make sense.) The ratio of the first to the second probability works out to be

$${(3N-6)(3N-7)(3N-8)\over20(N-2)^3}={3(3N-7)(3N-8)\over20(N-2)^2}$$

Some experimentation and/or algebra shows that this ratio is less than $1$ for $3\le N\le5$ and greater than $1$ for $N\ge6$.  So in general you are better off grabbing just another three items if your first grab gave you two of one type and one of another, unless you have reason to believe the box started out with only $9$, $12$, or $15$ items altogether.

Comment: The way I read the question, is that one learns whether it's a win or a loss after drawing the three items, but not whether it's a 0-1-2, or a 0-0-3. I also read the question as saying that the number of items left in the box is sufficiently "large", so that no matter how many and which I grab, they remain equiprobable. Under these assumptions, grabbing only 3 more yields a probability of success "on the second attempt" equal to 2/21, while grabbing 6 more a probability of (2/21)x(190/243), which is strictly less.

Comment: @Anonymous, ah, I think your reading of the question is correct.  I couldn't make sense of the parenthetical "(knowing that the quantities are different, but without knowing the quantities)" so I wound up ignoring it, but I see now how it fits your reading. I'll give the matter some more thought.

Comment: I understand your answer, but I should not know if I got 3 equal elements, or 2 of one and 1 of the other. I only need to know if I win or lost on the first attempt, so if I lost I got to choose 3 or 6.

Answer (score 3):

Let's get one thing cleared up! The "law of large numbers" tells you -- roughly speaking -- that with more events you are more likely to get *approximately* what you expect, rather than *exactly* what you expect. For example, it's far harder to get *exactly* $1000$ tails and $1000$ heads out of $2000$ tosses than $1$ tail and $1$ head out of $2$ tosses.

As a very, very rough approximation, for problems such as this, with $n$ independent events, you can think that about half of the "probability mass" is concentrated within the average plus or minus a quantity that is proportional to $\sqrt{n}$; and within this "standard deviation" all results are more or less as likely as each other (within a constant factor).

Then, getting results within an interval *proportional* to the number of events (say, average $\pm 10\%$) becomes easier with large numbers. Getting results within an interval proportional to the *square root* of the number of events (say, average $\pm 20\%$ for a given $n$, or average $\pm 5\%$ when $n$ is $16$ times larger $(20/5=\sqrt{16})$ stays roughly the same. Getting results within an interval that is independent of the number of events (say, average $\pm 10$ - note, $10$, not $10\%$) becomes *harder* with large numbers.

But note that for subtle situations like this one, with conditional probabilities etc. such rough reasoning is dangerous and easily leads to mistakes!